# How to pass HWND with InvokeHelper for calling .NET COM object?

Tags: c++, .net, com, marshalling, ole

### UPDATE

I have made a test project for the original question (that I moved below). 
C# code:

```
namespace TestManagedCom
{
   [ComVisible(true)]
   public class DummyObject
   {
      public void Method1(int value)
      {
         IntPtr hwnd = new IntPtr(value);
         MessageBox.Show(string.Format("[Method1] value={0:X}, hwnd={1}", value, hwnd));
      }

      public void Method2(long value)
      {
         IntPtr hwnd = new IntPtr(value);
         MessageBox.Show(string.Format("[Method2] value={0:X}, hwnd={1}", value, hwnd));
      }
   }
}
```

C++ code:

```
class CDispatchWrapper : public COleDispatchDriver
{
public:
   CDispatchWrapper(){}
   CDispatchWrapper(LPDISPATCH pDispatch) : COleDispatchDriver(pDispatch) {}
   CDispatchWrapper(const CDispatchWrapper& dispatchSrc) : COleDispatchDriver(dispatchSrc) {}

   void CallMethod(DISPID dwDispID, int value)
   {
      static BYTE parms[] = VTS_I4;
      InvokeHelper(dwDispID, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_EMPTY, NULL, parms, value);
   }

   void CallMethod(DISPID dwDispID, long long value)
   {
      static BYTE parms[] = VTS_I8;
      InvokeHelper(dwDispID, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_EMPTY, NULL, parms, value);
   };
};

template <typename T>
void Execute(const CString& progId, const CString& methodName, T value)
{
   LPDISPATCH lpEventComponent = NULL;

   _com_ptr_t<_com_IIID<IDispatch, &IID_IDispatch> > pCreateComp;
   HRESULT hr = pCreateComp.CreateInstance(progId);
   if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && pCreateComp != NULL)
   {
      hr = pCreateComp.QueryInterface(IID_IDispatch, (void**)&lpEventComponent);

      if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
      {
         USES_CONVERSION;

         DISPID dwFunctionID = 0;
         OLECHAR FAR *szFunc = T2OLE(const_cast<LPTSTR>(methodName.GetString()));

         hr = lpEventComponent->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &szFunc, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dwFunctionID);

         if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && dwFunctionID != -1)
         {
            lpEventComponent->AddRef(); // released by the dispatch driver

            CDispatchWrapper wrapper(lpEventComponent);
            wrapper.CallMethod(dwFunctionID, value);
         }
      }
   }
}

Execute<int>(_T("TestManagedCom.DummyObject"), _T("Method1"), 0x11223344);
Execute<long long>(_T("TestManagedCom.DummyObject"), _T("Method2"), 0x1122334455667788LL);
```

It works well when the target is x64. It prints:

> [Method1] value=11223344, hwnd=287454020
>
> [Method2] value=1122334455667788, hwnd=1234605616436508552

The call to `Method2` throws an exeption when the target is x86.

> First-chance exception at 0x76A2B727 in TestOleDispatcher.exe:
>   Microsoft C++ exception: EEException at memory location 0x003FE3C4.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

I have tried with both `long long` and `__int64` and the error is obviously the same.

It seems that somehow it cannot correctly marshall `VTS_I8` params on x86.

### The original question

I have problems in some legacy code calling a method in a .NET class that represents a COM object with `COleDispatchDriver::InvokeHelper`. One of the parameters is the handle of a window.

The .NET code used to look like this (simplified):

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Sample
{
   public void Method1(int hwndParent)
   {
   }
}
```

And the C++ code

```
class CSendEventWrapper : public COleDispatchDriver
{
public:
   void CallMethod(DISPID dwDispID, long* hwnd)
   {
      static BYTE parms[] = VTS_PI4;
      InvokeHelper(dwDispID, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_EMPTY, NULL, parms, hwnd);
   }
};

HWND hWnd = ...;
long lval = (long)hWnd;
o.CallMethod(dispId, &lval); // snippet for calling the method
```

This worked OK when the C++ app was 32-bit only. But on a 64-bit version, this is not correct, since `HWND` is 64-bit and `long` is just 32-bit, so you lose data.

So I started changing the .NET code to use `IntPtr` instead of `int` (as it should have been in the first place).

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Sample
{
   public void Method1(IntPtr hwndParent)
   {
   }
}
```

But now the problem is how do I call it with `InvokeHelper`. I tried doing something like this:

```
void CallMethod(DISPID dwDispID, INT_PTR hwnd)
{
#ifdef _WIN64
   static BYTE parms[] = VTS_PI8;
#else
   static BYTE parms[] = VTS_PI4;
#endif
   InvokeHelper(dwDispID, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_EMPTY, NULL, parms, hwnd);
}

HWND hWnd = ...;
INT_PTR lval = (INT_PTR)hWnd; // 32- or 64-bit depending on the platform
o.CallMethod(dispId, &lval); // snippet for calling the method
```

However, this now results in an exception that says a parameter was in an incorrect format. `IntPtr` should be 32-bit or 64-bit depending on whether the process if 32-bit or 64-bit. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Any help for figuring how to correctly pass the HWND with `InvokeHelper` both for 32-bit and 64-bit versions is appreciated. (And no, I cannot replace the use of `COleDispatchDriver`).

Comment: Exception where?  Any exception details?

Comment: You seem, to have VTS_PI4 for 64-bit and VTS_PI8 for 32-bit.  Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: good point about that; was just an error when I edited the code in the browser. the actual code was correct about that.

Comment: MFC doesn't support VT_INT_PTR.  Just make it VTS_PI8 consistently, the managed code can cast to IntPtr in either bitness.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have mismatch of parameter types. Getting the handle from c# typically gives you the window handle in a IntPtr. This will be the actual handle, not a pointer to the handle. From your code it looks like you're expecting a pointer to handle. I can tell by the long* hWnd and VTS_PI4.

If the COM call really wants a INT_PTR (a pointer to the handle), you'll have to store the variable passed in and take the address of it to pass on. If it takes the window handle directly, then you'll need to modify the VTS_PI4/VTS_PI8 to VTS_I4/VTS_I8.